Object "Item" is used to modify data on Object "player"
I'm trying to code a simple text RPG using JS and I wanted to perform this:
I have two objects: Player and Item. "Potion" is one instance of Item, and it increases Player hp by 30 when used.
I'm using  the following code and it works fine, but I'd like to know if there is a "better" way to perform this without using "eval". Note that the "ef" key in the instance of Item must specify which keys of Player it affects and what it must do.
class Player {
    constructor(a={}) {
        this.na = a.na
        this.st = {hp: 100, atk: 10, def: 10, en: 50}
    }
}

class Item {
    static potion = new this({
        na: "Potion",
        ef: ['st.hp', '+= 30']
    })
    
    constructor(a={}) {
        this.na = a.na
        this.ef = a.ef ?? []
    }
    
    use(target) {
        eval(`target.${this.ef[0]} ${this.ef[1]}`)
    }
}

const me = new Player({na: "Azmuth"})
Item.potion.use(me)
console.log(me)

Sorry for bad english/explanation and thank you in advance.

I would just set this up differently. The fact that += 30 is stored as a string with the operator will force any solution to be hacky or obscure. Just store the number 30 (addition is implied since it's a positive number), and give the player a method called something like affectHp. Then have the potion's use just do target.affectHp(this.ef), where this.ef is 30. Then the player class can worry about setting the HP value.

And if you want items to be very general and capable of all sorts of arbitrary manipulations of players/whatever, you could have them store a function: this.ef = (player) => player.affectHp(30), then in use: this.ef(target).

Thank you very much for the suggestion. I confess I didn't thought about passing a function to the item effect. This gives me tons of possible effects to make.

I suggest to handle applying items in the player class since it has more info about itself to properly assign values, also storing data as an array isn't very good, just use separate properties. You can introduce negative values for assigning or a callback:


class Player {
    constructor(a={}) {
        this.na = a.na
        this.st = {hp: 100, atk: 10, def: 10, en: 50}
    }
    useItem(item){
        const {key, value} = item;
        let node = this;
        const path = key.split('.');
        const valKey = path.pop();
        for(const k of path){
          node = node[k] ??= {};
        }
        if(typeof value === 'function') node[valKey] = value(node[valKey]);
        else node[valKey] += value;
        return this;
    }
}

class Item {

    static potion = new this({
        na: "Potion",
        key: 'st.hp',
        value: 30
    })
    
    constructor(a = {}) {
        return a;
    }
    
}

const me = new Player({na: "Azmuth"})
me.useItem(Item.potion);
console.log(me)

me.useItem(new Item({key: 'st.atk', value: v => v * 2}));
console.log(me)




Really appreciated this approach! Thank you for your time. I'll rewrite my code based on your suggestion.
